# Excel referencing to cell in interactive table

Tags: excel

I have 5 tables. The blue one is table used for filling up the dropdown list, with numbers I chose. The red one is table with dropdown menu where I can choose items from the blue table (it transpones the rows, but not important), in this table I am using VLOOKUP function. The yellow one is table after doing a calculation. It takes values from the red table and applies a formula. The green one is the table I am having problems with. I want this table to show values from Item1 after applying the formula and the same for Item2, but everytime I change item from dropdown menu the values change as well and as in the picture both columns show values for only one item. My desired output is the grey table.
[image]

Comment: Use  the formula form the yellow table in the green table on the values in the blue table.

Comment: The problem is that this formula usually looks like this A*B+C where A and C are coeficients I would like to modify to see changes in results and B are values from the blue table. Furthermore each Item has its own formula and I already have the yellow table calculated for each item, all I need is this connection if any way possible. I decided to create a new post since the last one was very messy. I hope someone could now provide the solution, otherwise I am sticking either to this or last post's suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Data Table

### step 1

Write cell G11 with `=F5`, G12 with `=F6`.

### step 2

Select `G10:L12`

### step 3

Using `Data` -> `Data Tools` -> `What-if analysis` -> `data table`

### step 4

In the `data table` dialog, write `Row input cell` with cell D4, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, although I have already used your previous solution, I will mark this as answer for future reference.

Comment: Great answer! I totally forgot about the " What-if analysis"  option.